# Error in importin a module in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

So i'm trying to use this module called image-clipper(https://github.com/superRaytin/image-clipper) in a chrome extension and it doesnt seem to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bhgf.png)
for context i'm importing it in my background script

```
import imageClipper from './image-clipper.js';

imageClipper(dataUrl , function(){
        this.crop(200, 200, 200 , 200).toDataURL((URL)=>{
          chrome.tabs.create({url : URL})
        })
      })
```

and in the module code I added

```
export default imageClipper;
```

the image-clipper.js code is one of those unreadable codes (probably umd module idk i'm new to this) that starts with an anonymous of function or w/e.
Anyway it doesnt contain any explicit class named imageClipper. However this is how it's supposed to be used according to the doc of the module.

Comment: 1) It's a normal script, not a module. Remove your added `export`, remove `import`, remove `"type":"module"` from manifest.json, and use importScripts instead. 2) Looking at the script I see it uses `document` so it won't work in the service worker and you'll need to do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) or write a polyfill for the features used by the script or suggest its author to make a compatible version that uses OffscreenCanvas and createImageBitmap instead of DOM.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm testing what you suggested, but i want to note that i saw in another extension someone using the image-clipper with an import (https://github.com/lxieyang/screenshot-extension/) but i assume it's a different context right, idk i'm pretty new to all of this. And btw I added the export to the end of the script and right now i get error (window undefined)